# why I am getting HttpErrorResponse error in Angular?

Tags: php, angular6

I am trying to send http post request from my register.component.ts page to register_insert.php page. But I am getting HttpErrorResponse error. Where I am doing wrong? please help

**register.component.ts**

```
  insertData() {
      this.httpClient.post(
          "http://localhost/register_insert.php",
          {
              'fullname':this.fullname, 
              'email':this.email,
              'role':this.role,
              'typee':this.typee,
              'password':this.password,

          },   
      ).subscribe((data) => {
          alert("inserted");
          console.log(data);
          this.fullname = null;
          this.email = null;
          this.role = null;
          this.typee = null;
          this.password = null;
      }, 
      (err)=>{
        console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

**register_insert.php**

```
    <?php  

        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');
        header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Length, X-JSON");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");

include 'dbcon.php';

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
if(count($data) > 0 ) {

    $fullname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$data['fullname']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data['email']);
    $role = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$data['role']);
    $type = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data['typee']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$data['password']);



    $insert = "INSERT INTO tbl_user values ('','$fullname','$email','$role','$type','$password')";


    if(mysqli_query($connect,$insert)){
      echo "Data inserted";
    } else {
      echo "Data not inserted" . mysqli_error($connect);
    }
}
 ?>
```

[Screenshot of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czbGP.png)

[image]